# StopPolling a query polling used within multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, apollo-client

I have custom hook `useGetPosts` like this:

```
const useGetPosts = () => {
  const {data, isLoading, error, stopPolling, startPolling} = useQuery(GET_POSTS_GUERY);

  useEffect(() => {
    startPolling(10000);
  }, []);

  return {
    data,
    isLoading,
    error, 
    stopPolling
  }
}
```

I use it in multiple components to get posts data. The problem is that at some point I want to stopPolling the query and in one of components I call `stopPolling()` function, but it still refetches the data, because there are other mounted components calling this hook.

My idea was to add stopPolling functions into the array and when I want just to go through it and call all functions, but that doesn't look like a clean/best solution.

Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the hook into a higher level component
2. In the lower level components run the query with `fetch-policy: 'cache-only'`. This will avoid multiple network requests.
3. Only stop/start the top level polling.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. if you can provide code example it would be great. Thanks.